# Robust copy big size files filtered by extension between two drives and preserving each file-path?

Tags: powershell, robocopy, file-copying

I need to copy *.yxz files (about 500 files 20/30gb each one in separate dirs) from `v:\foo\bar\1\baz.xyz, v:\foo\bar\2\etc.xyz` to `m:\foo\bar\1\baz.xyz, m:\foo\bar\2\etc.xyz`... dest dirs contains other files...

I've tried with powershell but unfortunately doesn't works:

```
$mylist = Get-ChildItem -Path "v:\" -File -Recurse | Where-Object {( $_.Extension -match ".xyz" )}

$src = $mylist.FullName

$dst = $src | Split-Path
 
$dst = $dst.replace('V:','M:')

foreach ( $line in $src ) { robocopy/copy-item $line $dst }
```

Robocopy it would be better, but if it's not possible, I can get file hash from source and compare it with the destination...

I've to copy all files manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use $dst inside this loop you are calling the entire array of destinations each time. Instead you should be using the first source with the first destination and so on. You can use something like this:

```
foreach($line in (0..(($src.length)-1))) { robocopy $src[$line] $dst[$line] }
```

---

```
$line in (0..(($src.length)-1))
```

This loops through each element in the array '$src' and sets '$line' to be equal to the index.

```
{ robocopy $src[$line] $dst[$line] }
```

This calls the element in the array by putting the index. e.g. '$src[0]' will return the first element in an array.

I can't check the robocopy syntax but this should fix the issue with the loop.

Comment: @lanteu, You're absolut right lanteu, now the array is indexed correctly but, unfortunately seems that Robocopy treats each files as a directory and copy fails... If I use "copy-item" I get this error: `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.` But if I echos like that: `foreach ( $line in 0..$src.length ) { "$src[$line] $dst[$line]" }`, shell prints correctly source file and destination file alternately...

Comment: @Lanteu, this is the exact error:

`Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
Line:1 char:49
+ foreach ( $line in 0..$src.length ) { Copy-Item $src[$line] $dst[$lin ...
+                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand`

Comment: My mistake. It needs to be'foreach($i in (0..(($src.length)-1))){$i}'. It will try to do an extra element from this array, which doesn't exist, so will throw an error. Will edit my post.

Comment: @lanteu, Nice shot! Really thanks lanteu! if I wanted to add a progress bar in this code, `write-progress` cmdlet is it the right choice?

Comment: I solved (the `write.progress`) by myself!

`$i = 0;

foreach ($line in (0..(($src.length)-1))) {
Copy-Item $src[$line] $dst[$line];
$i++;
Write-Progress -activity "Copy in Progress . . ." -status "Copied: $i of $($src.Count)" -percentComplete (($i / $src.Count)  * 100)
}`